# Passing multiple template parameters for multiple template functions

Tags: c++, templates

I'm working on raii wrapper for Vulkan API objects (if you are not familiar with Vulkan API please don't leave, there's no problem with Vulkan itself). So I want to use one class for different objects with `using` and templates (such as `using raii_instance = raii_wrapper<vk::Instance...`). Different classes require different delete and create functions. They take different parameters. How can I specify parameters for functions in template list? If I only had had Func I would have used `...Args` after all typenames. But I need two functions. Here is my code:

```
template<typename VkObjectType, typename VkCreateFunc, typename VkDestroyFunc>
class raii_wrapper {
public:

    //...

    ~raii_wrapper() {
        _destroy(); //here I need to pass some parameters (from outside the class)
    }
    
    raii_wrapper& operator=(create_info<VkObjectType>& factory) {
        auto create_info = tools::get_CreateInfo<T>(factory);
        _create(); //here I need other parameters (from outside the class)
    }

private:
    //...
    
    VkCreateFunc _create;
    VkDestroyFunc _destroy;
};
```

Or should I create a separate struct/pair that contains std::function and its params? And invoke it like `std::invoke(struct.func, struct.params)` (params are a template for that struct I have mentioned) ?

I want to use my class as follows:

```
auto create_instance = [](auto create_info) { vk::createInstance(create_info); };
using create_instance_t = decltype(create_instance);

auto destroy_instance = [](auto instance) { instance.desctroy(); };
using destroy_instance_t = decltype(destroy_instance);

using raii_instance = raii_wrapper<vk::Instance, create_instance_t, destroy_instance_t>;
```

And I will be passing functions `create_instance` and `destroy_instance` as a constructor arguments

Comment: *"//here I need to pass some parameters"* Which ones? fixed from outside the class, from inside the class?

Comment: from outside the class of course

Comment: What specifically is wrong with just forwarding a parameter pack to whichever function you're calling? Compile errors too ugly? Something else?

Comment: bind the parameter in those type then?

Comment: that's my problem. i don't know how to bind them :(

Comment: should I use `std::bind` ? Wouldn't it be too complicated?

Comment: Those "parameters from outside the class" - how do they get into the class? How do you envision using `raii_wrapper` - can you show an example of that? Clearly parameters that the destructor needs to pass to `_destroy` have to be made available to the `raii_wrapper` object at some point prior to it being destroyed. Where and how do you imagine that would happen?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have modified a question. Would you mind reading it again?

Comment: So, what's `create_info` and `instance`, and how an object of type `raii_instance` would obtain them so that it could pass them along to `create_instance(...)` and `destroy_instance(...)`? You have a type named `raii_instance` - show how you would like to define and initialize an object of that type.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I want to type `raii_instance vk_instance(create_info);` where `decltype(create_info)` is `vk::InstanceCreateInfo`, which is needed for creator func. Roughly speaking, I need something like `template <typename VkObjectType, typename VkCreateFunc, typename VkDestroyFunc, typename...VkCreateArgs, typename...VkDestroyArgs>`

Comment: You probably want a templated constructor. Something like `template <typename ... Args> rai_wrapper(Args&&... args) : _create([=]() { VkCreateFunc()(args...); }) {}`, where `_create` would be `std::function<void()>`. Then whenever you are ready to call it, you just do `_create()`. The arguments are baked into the lambda that in turn is captured by `std::function`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik hi again! Sorry, I didn't have a chance to tell you that your idea worked perfectly, thank you! :)